# difference of final variable in code block

Tags: java

I see some code like

```
public void foo() {
    final int x = 3;
    final Object z = new Object();
    .......
}
```

I know that x can't be modified since it is final but is there any other reason/explaination for that? compare to without using final? Or the developer just added final to that variable because he just likes to. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "is there any other reason for that"? Could you clarify your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring a variable immutable (final) is a pretty good reason by itself. Besides adding clarity to the code, it also provides some valuable information to the compiler that might be able to optimize code better when it knows that some things are not going to change.

One other reason might be hidden in your example behind the ellipsis: if there is a closure somewhere in that function, that references this local variables, it would not compile if they were not final. Imagine something like this for example:

```
public void foo() {
    final int x = 3;
    final Object z = new Object();
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                System.out.println(z);
            }
        }
    }.start();
}
```

For this to work, x and z must be declared final. Why? Well, local variables are created on stack, and, once the function returns, they disappear completely. But the code inside the `Thread.run()` method defined here, might still be executing, after the function that created it returns. Because the variables are final, their values are known to the JVM at the time the closure is created, so it can simply copy the values into the closure. If they weren't final, it would not be possible, because the copies would become stale as soon as the original value is modified.

Comment: Thanks, Im enlighten by this explaination.

Answer (score 1):

1) A final class cannot be extended

2) A final method cannot be overridden

3) Final fields, parameters, and local variables cannot change their value once set

4) Declaring primitive fields as final automatically ensures thread-safety for that field

5) Clearly communicates your intent

6) Allows the compiler and virtual machine to perform minor optimizations

7) Clearly flags items which are simpler in behaviour - final says, "If you are looking for complexity, you won't find it here."

Answer (score 1):

No there is no other reason, other than not letting others change the value (objects, primitives) but this doesn't prevent them from changing values in the class (for example, `final Dog dog = new Dog()` would prevent others from changing the reference to the dog object, but wouldn't prevent us from changing the variable inside it, for example, the size value of the dog)

Comment: Has the original poster seen this answer?

Comment: yes I read this, and I want more aside from this. Your answer is appreciated.